# What is the type of AC power in Power supply/Adaptor rating?

Tags: power-supply, power, ac, adapter

Most of times, Power Supply or Adapter has an annotation related to the power rating such as in this figure

[image]

For the red underlined value, I understand that it is the actual delivered DC power, and the current is the maximum current. But for the AC part, is it true power or total power?
If it is total power, Could I get the power factor from rated DC power and AC total power?

Thank you

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're concerned about the power factor of such a small load?

Comment: @KH , there is no any reason, the figure only an example of adapter, just curious because there is no explanation whether it is total or true power

Answer (score 0):

It’s unlikely that you would get a meaningful power factor - the 1.6A is presumably the maximum at the lowest supply voltage (100V) and probably has a safety margin built in.  The difference between the ongoing and outgoing power gives you the efficiency of the device (about 85% is typical).  Measuring the power factor is a more complex task; there are a few ways to measure it.

Comment: So the 1.6A and 100V gives the total power right? not true power of AC? Thank you for the answer